# Referencing an array of IBOutlet 's (NSButton)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I am making an application where there are 32 Check Box, and a NSTextField.
If the user clicks on the NSTextField the buttons shall assume the value that describes the binary rappresentation of this number.
No problem receiving the "clicked" action on the NSTextField, but for the buttons I have declared an array of 32 NSButtons:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Handler : NSObject 
{
    @private
    IBOutlet NSTextField* textField;
    IBOutlet NSButton* bits[32];     // here are the buttons
}

- (void)awakeFromNib;
- (void) setTextField : (int) value;
- (int) getTextField;
@end
```

But when I try to link a Check Box with the IBOutlet "bits", I can't do it for each member.
So I can only make that array of 32 pointers to NSButton to one box.
I also show an image:

[image: Interface builder]

This is a problem for me, do I have to manually declare 32 different outlets with 32 different names?

Comment: Are the checkboxes all related (meaning they serve a common functionality)? If so, you are probably looking to use an NSMatrix object, where you can access each object via tag number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a good example of using an NSMatrix object.

You can add one button to your interface and then with the button selected in Xcode 4 go to Editor > Embed In > Matrix. Then you can option drag on a corner of the button to expand it into a matrix.

NSMatrix allows you to retrieve the cell values by searching for a given tag or by column/row coordinates.

HOW TO: 
1) Embedding the NSButton object:

[image: Creating a button matrix]

2) Option-Drag any of the button corners to expand the matrix:

[image]

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Check my updated post, it should work for you.

Comment: Note: `NSMatrix` is discouraged from 10.8 and unavailable in the Editor > Embed In

Comment: Yup! You're very right. NSMatrix is discouraged and you're probably better off implementing something like this using `NSGridView` or `NSStackView`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to use 32 different `IBOutlet` references.  You can declare an `IBOutletCollection`:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Use this to link them all up.  Keep in mind that the order of the buttons is non-deterministic at runtime, meaning, you cannot guarantee that the buttons will be in any specific order when the app is running.

Comment: Isn't this an iOS only feature?

Comment: I think you're right Lucas, I tried it and I got this error:  
_expected ';' at end of declaration list_  
But the ';' is already a at end of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded it into a matrix.But graphically it looks like a single button.
This is what I get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once you embed it in the matrix, you now have to option drag from any of the corners of the button and this will make more check boxes for you.